# Find log(x) using python

Tags: python, math, logging

how can I solve this question plot Log(x) where 0<=x<= 3*pi by using python?

```
t = np.arange(0.01, 20.0, 0.01)
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.subplot(222)
plt.semilogx(t, np.sin( 3*np.pi*t))
```

Comment: Your question lacks focus on the specific programming problem you encountered while trying to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# use np.linspace to create x-points
t = np.linspace(0.01, 3*np.pi, 50)
plt.plot(t, np.log(t));
```

Comment: I doubt that this helps, or even works at all. To convince me otherwise please provide some explanation of how this works and why it is supposed to help. That would also help fighting the misconception that StackOverflow is a platform for finding unpaid programming work.